# Date format not recognised in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT TO_DATE(UPDATED_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM/PM')
FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

Iam getting error saying date format not recognised.
UPDATED_DATE is my column of varchar2 datatype

Comment: Don't store dates as strings.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `AM` or `PM` (not both) and the `FF` format model is only used with `TO_TIMESTAMP` or `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` (not `TO_DATE`, as dates do not have fractional seconds).

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(
         UPDATED_DATE,
         'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM'
       )
FROM   tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE tw_edu_infra_amenities (updated_date) AS
SELECT '01-02-2003 12:34:56.789 AM' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TO_TIMESTAMP(UPDATED_DATE,'DD-MM-YYYYHH12:MI:SS.FFAM') |
| --- |
| 2003-02-01 00:34:56.789000000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D0TeE7Lm)

Answer (score 0):

Can you be certain what the format for that date will actually be in that varchar2 column? What if there is something there which cannot possibly be converted to date?
Therefore I would rather advise you to use something like TO_TIMESTAMP(         UPDATED_DATE default null on conversion error,'DD-MM-YYYY HH12:MI:SS.FF AM').
If you know the date might have been entered in several formats, you may do something like below:

```
coalesce(to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'dd-mm-yyyy')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'dd-mm-rr')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'dd-mon-rr')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'mm/dd/rr')
 ,to_date(updated_date default null on conversion error,'mm/dd/yyyy')
)
```

I think this way you may cover situations when the input does not always respect a standard.

Answer (score -1):

the format of the date string in the UPDATED_DATE column does not match the format string that you're using in the TO_DATE() function

```
SELECT TO_DATE(UPDATED_DATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM tw_edu_infra_amenities;
```

Make sure to replace 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM' with the actual format of the date string in your column. You can find more information about date format strings in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E57185_01/DRMAG/date-time_format_strings.htm#DRMAG-drm_Admin_Manage_Properties_9) :

Comment: "the format of the date string in the UPDATED_DATE column does not match the format string" is incorrect as the OP's error is "date format not recognised" which means they are using a format model that is not valid for the `TO_DATE` function (and does not mean that the data is invalid).